# create a restricted link for a group of users spring

Tags: spring, security, jwt

how can i restrict a link to a group access ,in a manner that an admin from group one can't access a link from group 2 ,I did use jwt to secure the application
thank you

Comment: When receiving a request, you check that the current user belongs to the group allowed to make such a request. Before displaying the list, you check that the current user is allowed to see such a link. With so few details in your questions, that's pretty much all we can say.

Comment: her is the probleme ,using jwt only acode restriction to a link using ROLES however, i have many groups and every group contains an admin and users ,so just by the roles the links are not restricted to a user or an admin of the other group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a verification service to verifie if the user is member of  a group group or not ,then i created a compoenent  to get hold of pathvariable for the name of group .

component code :

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RequestHelper {
private final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;
public Object getPathVariableByName(String name) {
    final Map pathVariables = (Map) httpServletRequest.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE);
    return pathVariables.get(name);
}}
```

anotation example

```
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER') and @securityServices.hasAccess(@requestHelper.getPathVariableByName('groupName')))")
```

sevice code example

```
@Service
public class SecurityServices {


public boolean hasAccess(String groupName) {
   return true or false //acording to your case if users in the group or not 
}}
```